# Change WebView position Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I'm quite a newbie to Cocoa & Mac programming. I have a WebView and I want to move it. Is there a way to change the coordinates of the WebView?

EDIT: Some relevant code:
NistractAppDelegate.m

```
#import "NistractAppDelegate.h"

@implementation NistractAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    [window setAlphaValue:0];
    [window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.125490196078431 green:0.125490196078431 blue:0.125490196078431 alpha:1]];
    [mainWebView setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.125490196078431 green:0.125490196078431 blue:0.125490196078431 alpha:1]];
    [[mainWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
    mainWebView.frame = NSMakeRect(mainWebView.frame.origin.x + 10, mainWebView.frame.origin.y, mainWebView.frame.size.width, mainWebView.frame.size.height);

    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    [[window animator] setAlphaValue:1];


}

@end
```

NistractAppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface NistractAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow *window;
    IBOutlet NSView *mainView;
    IBOutlet id mainWebView;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to move the entire webview you need set it's frame.

```
WebView.frame = NSMakeRect(x,y,width,height);
```

Eg if you want to just shift it left by ten pixels:

```
WebView.frame = NSMakeRect(WebView.frame.origin.x + 10, WebView.frame.origin.y, WebView.frame.size.width, WebView.frame.size.height);
```

When in doubt always you look in the documentation, which you can do from within side XCode, by selecting some text and right clicking then selecting Find Text In Documentation

Or use Google by searching "{Class name} class reference" Eg "nsview class reference"

Comment: It says: "error: request for member 'frame' in something not a structure or union"

Comment: WebView in my answer must be replaced with the name of your webview instance: `mywebview.frame = ....` also I made mistake in the answer which I've corrected now.

Comment: I have replaced WebView by mainWebView, the name of my webview, but it still gives the same error. Do I have to initialize the webview somehow to accept these expressions?

Comment: You shouldn't have to if your using interface builder. Can you post some relevant code in your question? Try typing `mainWebView.` and then pressing Esc it should show a list of properties you can use. See if frame is in that list.

Comment: I am using interface builder, so that shouldn't be a problem. The list of properties contains frame, so I don't understand why it doesn't work. I'll try to post some relevant code in my question.

Comment: Ah right do you get any warnings about the loadRequest line? You need to change `id` in the line `IBOutlet id mainWebView;` to `WebView` if it throws an error/warning on that, try importing WebView.h into your header file.

Comment: Yes, it says "No -mainFrame method found" but the loadRequest works. How do I import WebView.h?

Comment: Thanks, I succeeded to import webview by adding #import <WebKit/WebView.h> Thank you very much! Now the code works!